# Sharepoint - Removing Enterprise Keywords

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, term-set, enterprise-keywords

Do I need to manually remove Enterprise Keywords from my Term Store Management?

I am not certain but it appears once Enterprise Keywords have been activated for a list or library - in this case the default management which is 'Open' is applied that the keywords are added to the Term Store but are not automatically removed when the document or list item being described with the EK is deleted.

Is this how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Enterprise Keywords will automatically add to term store but are not automatically removed when items are deleted.

We need to manually deleted them in the term store management tool.